# Get setTimeout delay from timeoutID

Tags: javascript, dom-events, settimeout

How can one find the timeout delay based on the `timeoutID` (and if not possible by the `timeoutID`, then perhaps something else such as the timeout object, etc)

```
timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 2000);
getOriginalTimeoutValue(timeoutId);

function getOriginalTimeoutValue(timeoutId) {
   // find original timeout delay (i.e. 2000)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can one find the timeout delay based on the timeout ID (and if not possible by the timeout ID, then perhaps something else such as the timeout object, etc

You can't, at all. That information is not provided by any browser API. You could write a wrapper around `setTimeout` to do it (perhaps even replacing the default one), but it's not something that's available out of the box.

A quick-and-dirty version of your own functions for this might look something like this (I've stuck with ES5-level stuff, so no `Map`), but be sure to subject it to code review, this is just dashed off:

```
(function(global) {
    // For our active timers
    var timers = {};
    // setTimeout wrapper with one that remembers the ID and delay
    global.mySetTimeout = function(callback, delay) {
        // Grab any args passed after delay
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            // Forget the ID
            delete timers[timer];
            // Call the callback
            return callback.apply(null, args);
        }, delay);
        timers[timer] = delay;
        return timer;
    };
    // clearTimeout wrapper to delete our record
    global.myClearTimeout = function(timer) {
        delete timers[timer];
        clearTimeout(timer);
    };
    // Create a new global function to get the delay
    global.getTimeoutDelay = function(timer) {
        return timers[timer];
    };
})(this);
```

Or if you really needed to replace the global functions (not usually a good idea):

```
(function(global) {
    // For our active timers
    var timers = {};
    // The original functions
    var origSetTimeout = setTimeout;
    var origClearTimeout = clearTimeout;
    // Replace setTimeout with one that remembers the ID and delay
    setTimeout = function(callback, delay) {
        // Grab any args passed after delay
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
        var timer = origSetTimeout(function() {
            // Forget the ID
            delete timers[timer];
            // Call the callback
            return callback.apply(null, args);
        }, delay);
        timers[timer] = delay;
        return timer;
    };
    // Replace clearTimeout to delete our record
    clearTimeout = function(timer) {
        delete timers[timer];
        origClearTimeout(timer);
    };
    // Create a new global function to get the delay
    global.getTimeoutDelay = function(timer) {
        return timers[timer];
    };
})(this);
```

This is **just a start** (and untested), you might find — at least — that you want to handle `clearInterval` as well (since it can clear a timer set with `setTimeout`).

Comment: Thanks TJ.  Well, at least I can quit looking and investigate different solutions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `map` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map  I've never used it but will investigate for other uses.

Comment: Would your two examples be initially called using `this.setTimeout(someFunc,2000);`  or `this.setTimeout(function(){/*..*/},2000);`  EDIT.  or is only `getTimeoutDelay` publicly available?  If so, how is it initiated?

Comment: @user1032531: You wouldn't use `this` at all. Other than that, either form, depending on your needs.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that you had `setTimeout ()` and `clearTimeout ()` globally defined and are just called using `setTimeout ()` or `window.setTimeout ()`.  But then, wouldn't `getTimeoutDelay()` need to be called using `this.getTimeoutDelay()`?  And why not do all three methods either one way or the other?  Also, I probably need to change `setTimeout ()` to return the timer ID, right?

Comment: @user1032531: You'd call `getTimeoutDelay` just like the others. The code above assumes it's written at global scope, so `this` is a reference to the global object, so the IIFE receives that as `global`, so assigning to `global.getTimeoutDelay` creates a new global. (I've fixed `setTimeout`/`mySetTimeout` above -- that's what I meant by code review! :-) )

Comment: Gotcha on the global part.  Please see https://jsfiddle.net/f10aztdq/1/.  Why isn't the `console.log` in `mySetTimeout()` not triggered?  Why does `getTimeoutDelay()` return `undefined`?

Comment: @user1032531: You've used the "your own functions" version of the above, but then tried to call it via `setTimeout`. You'd call `mySetTimeout` with those, or you'd use the others.

Comment: My stupid mistake.  On top of that, was testing in jsfiddle which I learned will not work with JavaScript in the HTML unless set to `no wrap - in <body>`.  You've been very generous with your time, and one last question.   While it will work as is, `myClearTimeout = function(timer) {..}` should be changed to `global.myClearTimeout = function(timer) {..}` so that all methods are applied to the same scope, right?

Comment: @user1032531: Yes (I've fixed it above, editing error). It has nothing to do with scope, though. It's just without the `global.` part, that code would be relying on [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can't. The API doesn't expose that information. You have to track it yourself.

```
var timeout_data = {};
timeout_data.time = 2000;
timeout_data.id = setTimeout(slowAlert, timeout_data.time);
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin,  Yes, will plan on tracking as you show.